# display oldest posts in a blog page php

Tags: php, wordpress, posts

I want to have a blog page which contains 4 posts, the user can see the other posts when he press the link "older posts", but I can't make this work. When I press the link it directs to a blank page.

```
  <?php
  $args = array( 'numberposts' => 4); 
  $posts= get_posts( $args );
  if ($posts) {
      foreach ( $posts as $post ) { ?>
  
        <article>
          <header>
            <h1><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h1>
          </header>

          <footer>
            <p><?php the_time('j F Y'); ?>
            <!-- <br>Publié par <?php the_author_meta('display_name', 1); ?></p> -->
          </footer>


          <div>
            <?php //echo catch_content_image($post->post_content) ?>
            <?php the_excerpt() ?>
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Suite de l'article</a>
          </div>
        </article>
      <?php
      }
  }
  ?>

<nav>
  <ul>

    <li class="older"><a href="blog-2.html">← Articles précédents</a></li> 
  
  
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe your issue is this line.

```
<li class="older"><a href="blog-2.html">← Articles précédents</a></li>
```

Try using something like this instead:

```
$prev = get_previous_posts_link();
echo $prev;
```

or to go forward

```
echo get_next_posts_link('Go to next page',4);
```

You could get more information on that here:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_next_posts_link